# REPLACE into keeping a value

Tags: mysql

I want to make a replace into in a table where cust_id is the primary key, but I do not want to modify the date field. So, a normal insert on this table would look like:

```
    REPLACE INTO emails(cust_id, email, date) 
VALUES(55, 'email@email.com', '2011-08-07 00:00');
```

Now, without having to modify the date field, it would be something such as:

```
REPLACE INTO emails(cust_id, email, date) 
VALUES(55, 'email@email.com', date.value?);
```

But how do I exactly keep the date value?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use `REPLACE` and not `UPDATE` ?

Comment: What should the initial value of `date` be?

Comment: @luqita: Not really irrelevant.

Comment: This can be done using mysql variables and my answer posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218185/mysql-replace-into-only-some-fields/74359590#74359590 shows how this can be done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer, You can't keep the dates that way. from [Mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

> Values for all columns are taken from the values specified in the
>   REPLACE statement. Any missing columns are set to their default
>   values, just as happens for INSERT. **You cannot refer to values from
>   the current row and use them in the new row**

perhaps you want to use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html instead.

Answer (score 5):

`insert ignore` will skip insertion if any duplication

if you need to update certain fields ,
you can do

```
insert into some_table values (...)
on duplicate update email=?;
```

Comment: But I want to replace the email field.

Comment: @luqita that's what the query is doing, if the primary key already exists it will only update the email field

Comment: had similar issue. needed to update some fields, keep some fields untouched and insert new rows from select query at the same time. that syntax helped
`insert into tableName  (...) (select ...) on duplicate key update count=temp1.count;`