# MYSQL - How to REPLACE INTO with some same value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
|   Name   |     ID     |     PHONE    |    CLASS    |
------------------------------------------------------
|  JASON   |    00101   | 035577871234 |    SA101    |
|  MERRY   |    00101   | 031996672211 |    SA102    |
|  MANNY   |    00101   | 035227443091 |    SA101    |
|  QUEEN   |    00101   | 035885811221 |    SA101    |
```

I need to `replace into` the table except `Name` column.

```
$sql="replace into employees values ('$name','$id','$phone','class')";
```

How should I do if I want the `Name` column the be remain? Or I should write a new query to get the value of Name, store it in a variable, and put the variable into the `replace into` query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218185/mysql-replace-into-only-some-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218185/mysql-replace-into-only-some-fields)

Comment: Add the fields to your sql like you would in an insert? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html

Answer (score 2):

The [`REPLACE INTO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) syntax is nearly the same as the [`INSERT INTO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) syntax, so you can specify a column list and exclude the `Name` column:

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO employees (ID, PHONE, CLASS) VALUES ('$id', '$phone', '$class')";
```

**Note:** With your specified code you write the value "class" to the `CLASS` column every time. It looks like you missed the `$` there (`class` to `$class`).